# Ajax function on button press

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get information to post via PHP on button click, everything in my code looks right, and when I view the page source everything is filled in the way it should be. When I pull up the debugger when the button is clicked it does not make any calls at all, here is my button

```
<button type="button">Continue</button>
```

here is my ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){

        var Id = <?php echo $give ?>;
        var Ids = <?php echo $rec ?>;
        var ex = <?php echo $exchange ?>;
        var ret = <?php echo $tost ?>;
        var email = <?php echo $email ?>;
        var name = <?php echo $name ?>;
        var pe = <?php echo $pe ?>;
        var re = <?php echo $re ?>;

        $.post("postts.php", { 
            Id: Id,
            Ids: Ids,
            ex: ex,
            ret: ret,
            email: email,
            name: name,
            pe: pe,
            re: re

        }, function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("p").text(data);
        }, 'json' );
    });
});
```

all of my `vars` will populate with the correct information, I just don't know why when I click the button it does nothing. I am not sure if I have made a typo, or if my syntax is wrong, this is only the second time I have done something like this.

Comment: And no errors in the console?

Comment: Maybe a typo: `postts.php` ?

Comment: Does it have to do that you spelled `posts` as `postts` and that could be potentially the wrong file?

Comment: is it meant to be `$.post("postts.php", { ... }` with two "t's"??  and have you tried just console logging anything?

Comment: Try this and see if you get any output in console...

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
   console.log('BUTTON CLICKED');
});`

Comment: No it is supposed to be spelled `postts.php`

Comment: It is giving me an error I didn't notice till now. It says `SyntaxError: illegal character` when I click it, it shows that none of my `php variables` are being passed, but when I check the page source they are, why would it be doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in writing variable values from PHP to JavaScript, you must wrap PHP output by quotation marks, so JavaScipt will "see" string ;)

instead of:
     `var email = <?php echo $email ?>;`
write:
    `var mail = '<?php echo $email ?>';`

Comment: Before I go asking another question can you see what I may have done that keeps the alert box from popping up

Comment: I guess you do not want to popup to appear? If so, just comment out or delete line `alert(data)`

Comment: No, the popup is not appearing and I am wanting it to

Comment: Best way find out this problem is to debug code step by step in browser on the fly. Problem can be caused by bad request URL, response error, bad response format, connection error... I do not know your skils, but every browser (nowadays) has debug tool under key "F12".

Comment: I have been using my console but everything looks good, I'm not getting any errors, that is why I am so confused :/

Comment: First step is to check, if there are error in console. Then check if the request was sent from client and if it is correctly received on server. 
Next step is if response is correctly send from server. Check server request response part in browser.